# Force UITableViewCell to keep objects right-aligned on orientation change

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell. The textLabel.text is set to some value. To the cell's subview, I add either a UILabel, UIButton or a UITextField (just one of these per cell). I add those views using a CGRectMake, which means I have to specify the X position.

But when I change the iPad's orientation, the UITableViewCell stretches and so the UILabel, UIButton or the UITextField isn't right aligned anymore. It is a few pixels off to the left, which makes it look ugly.

How can I make the objects on the right-hand side stay right-aligned, even when the orientation changes?

(If you go to iPad's "Settings" -- see the settings on the right view -- any orientation changes, and they stay glued to the right-end of the UITableViewCell. That's the effect I'm after here.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, figured it out! You can just set the UITableViewCell's accessoryView property to the control object and it just works!

```
cell.accessoryView = the_control
```

No need to mess around with anything else. I found this out by reading th[e Table View Programming Guide for the iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html) from the [iOS Developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/), which I should've done in the first place :-)

Comment: I was trying to align a button within a UITableViewCell that was in a grouped UITableView.  I kept on trying to align it within the contentView, but the width only took up so much of the cell.  Also, the UITableView doesn't give the horizontal margins.  This solved my problem though.  No alignment needed.  Thanks!!!

Comment: by the_control you mean the UIControl element, like the button.. i got it.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `autoresizingMask` property of the to-be-glued view such that it keeps a fixed distance from the right edge. In IB this is point-and-click, in code this is done by

```
 myview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin
```

Comment: From your explanation I cannot deduce the exact structure of your views, but if the view is not a direct subview of the tableviewcell, you should take care to set the autoresizingmasks of the views between them.